# trim String and add to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

the variable TEST is equal to this

```
lazar108@hotmail.com_Hd_s lazar108@hotmail.com_Update_on the lazar108@hotmail.com_Ksks_ajsj
```

i want to pull each "product" out so i have an ArrayList equal to this

```
lazar108@hotmail.com_Hd_s
lazar108@hotmail.com_Update_on
lazar108@hotmail.com_Ksks_ajsj
```

Right now the only thing in my array list is **lazar108@hotmail.com_Hd_s**

> How can i pull each "product" from the one variable (TEST) in a loop and add it to the ArrayList?

My code so far:

```
String TEST = result;

ArrayList<String> Products = new ArrayList<>();
boolean flag = true;

    while(flag == true){
      Products.add(TEST.substring(0, TEST.indexOf(' ')));
      TEST = TEST.substring(TEST.indexOf(' ') + 1);

          if(TEST.equals("")){
               flag = false;
          }else{
               TEST = TEST.substring(1);
           }
    }
```

[image: see]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your one step away from doing it. After the first iteration of your while loop, you do retrieve lazar108@hotmail.com_Hd_s, but after that the loop runs infinitely because the other parts of the string are not being accessed. The solution is to cut out the part you retrieved from the string each time you add it to `Products`. I should also note that this will only work if `TEST` ends with a space " ". Here is a way to approach this.

```
String TEST = result;

ArrayList<String> Products = new ArrayList<>();
boolean flag = true;

while(flag == true){
  Products.add(TEST.substring(0,TEST.indexOf(' ')));
  TEST = TEST.substring(TEST.indexOf(' '));//cutting the last email added from the string
    if(TEST.equals(" ")){
       flag = false;
    }
    else{
       TEST = TEST.substring(1); //remove that space so that it doesn't get  
                                 //counted again in the next iteration
    }

}
```

Comment: i think because of the " " at the end of TEST its not working

Comment: Would you prefer it to work without the " " at the end?

Comment: oh never mind it works! but for reference later could you take away the " " at the end?

Comment: also the second time it runs the loop the "product" losses the "l" at the beginning!

Comment: what "I"? also, you can't take out the " " with this code because you need the " " to separate each email from each other. To make it work without the " " at the end, you would have to check TEST to see if there are any spaces left to signify the last email being added.

Comment: what i mean by the "l" being missing is the first product is "lazar..." then the second product and all the ones after are mission the "l" at the start of "lazar..."

Comment: The emails are separated by a " " correct? If so, it shouldn't be skipping over the "l" because it's only skipping over the " ".

Comment: I added a photo of what i mean so you can see it better

Comment: Very strange, because I tested it out myself and it seems to work. I did fix one minor issue that you may have caught already if(TEST.equals("")) should be if(TEST.equals(" "))

Comment: really maybe i missing something (i updated the code), and if i add the space then it wont work

Comment: I ran my code word for word and it works. Unless result is something else, then it should work. Would you like to move this discussion to chat?

Comment: nope my code was wrong compared to yours! i changed it and now it works perfectly! Thank you! The reason why this sit is so amazing is because of people like you!!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative one line solution using *[String.split()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)* function:

```
List<String> products = Arrays.asList(TEST.split(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your input string doesn't simply have email separated by white space, I suggest you use `Pattern` and `Matcher`. First you need to define the email's pattern (you can google it), then use the example in this : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm